# iOS - Need to distinguish UILocalNotification in application:didReceiveLocalNotification:

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uilocalnotification

So here's the deal... I need a way to distinguish from what application state I received a `UILocalNotification`.

There is one scenario that for me I don't understand. That is when the app is currently running in the foreground and the user pulls down the Notification Center (iOS 5) then the app will get called `applicationWillResignActive:` which is perfectly logical because it will not be active when the Notification Center will be displayed over it. But I would suspect that also `applicationDidEnterBackground:` would get called right after it has resigned active **BUT** it does not. So when I receive UILocalNotifications when in the Notification Center my app will try to deal with them in `application:didReceiveLocalNotification:` but when I tap on a notification from my app that is in the Notification Center list then my app will deal with this notification the same way as it did when I received it in the Notification Center. So I can only handle these notifications in just one way but I would need to handle them in two ways.

So how would I distinguish between these two situations:

- When the app is in the foreground and the user has pulled down the
  Notification Center and I receive a notification during that time
  (`UIApplicationState = UIApplicationStateInactive`)
- When the app is in the foreground and the user has pulled down the
  Notification Center and actively chooses one of my app's
  notifications from the list (`UIApplicationState =

  UIApplicationStateInactive`)

**EDIT:**

I store all my notifications with a timestamp with 00 seconds. So inside `application:didReceiveLocalNotification:` I could check the current time `[NSDate date]` and see if the seconds are bigger than 00? That would mean that it's not iOS who has triggered the notification but the user from the notification center. This of course relays on the fact that the notifications will in fact be delivered by iOS in this timely manner. If iOS will deliver the notification at 01 seconds my logic will break. But for the sake of it I just did some logging to see when iOS delivers my notifications and it seems that judging from the output from the console the notifications are actually delivered on time with millisecond precision (+/- 1). Of course you can't compare a development device hooked up to the computer with a real world scenario.

```
2012-07-08 10:09:00.789 App[7535:707] -[AppDelegate application:didReceiveLocalNotification:] [Line 399] application:didReceiveLocalNotification: method running
2012-07-08 10:10:00.789 App[7535:707] -[AppDelegate application:didReceiveLocalNotification:] [Line 399] application:didReceiveLocalNotification: method running
2012-07-08 10:11:00.788 App[7535:707] -[AppDelegate application:didReceiveLocalNotification:] [Line 399] application:didReceiveLocalNotification: method running
2012-07-08 10:12:00.790 App[7535:707] -[AppDelegate application:didReceiveLocalNotification:] [Line 399] application:didReceiveLocalNotification: method running
2012-07-08 10:13:00.790 App[7535:707] -[AppDelegate application:didReceiveLocalNotification:] [Line 399] application:didReceiveLocalNotification: method running
2012-07-08 10:14:00.789 App[7535:707] -[AppDelegate application:didReceiveLocalNotification:] [Line 399] application:didReceiveLocalNotification: method running
2012-07-08 10:15:00.789 App[7535:707] -[AppDelegate application:didReceiveLocalNotification:] [Line 399] application:didReceiveLocalNotification: method running
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you just wait to see if your state becomes active shortly afterwards?

When you get a local notification in your second case, your app will be becoming active right after you get the callback (since the user is choosing to return to your app). So, how about storing your local notification and acting on it (say) 50ms later; if your application state is active at that point, the user selected your app from the notification center.

Comment: I've tried to flesh it out more. Let me know if it's still not clear.

Comment: Aha! That is a smart way to do it. I thought of another way, since I'm storing my notifications with a timestamp of 00 seconds I could check the timestamp when I receive the notification. What do you think is the more "safe" and elegant way to do this?

Comment: I would guess that local notifications can be significantly delayed in real-world use (if the device is in low-power, etc.) Also, the user could open your notification at 00, as well (and probably will, about 1 in 60 times they open a notification).

Comment: So, I'd probably still go with my method, though I don't think I'd describe it as "elegant" or "safe". Honestly, if the behaviour is what you describe (you get the local notification delivered directly to your app, even when you're not active) you should file a bug, because that's not what the documentation says should happen.

Comment: The app is actually not in an "inactive" state if it has posted "will resign active" notification. Although it is about to get inactive but that doesn't seem to be the case when the Notification Center is pulled over your active app. Though I'm still using 5.0.1 perhaps it has been fixed in 5.1.

Comment: It sounds like you're inactive if your application state is UIApplicationStateInactive. Apple's docs say that it won't deliver notifications when you're in that state unless the user has tapped on the notification.

Comment: Well actually I'm not sure what state my application is in when Notification Center is visible over my app. What I do know is that the last UIApplicationDelegate method that is posted before the Notification Center is overlayed is applicationWillResignActive: then no more UIApplicationDelegate methods are posted while Notification Center is overlayed.

Comment: Well, you're inactive when the notification is delivered, right? Isn't that the whole problem?

Comment: Yep that is true and according to the documentation the delegate method should only get called when the application is in the foreground. I've filed a bug report (ID 11827282). Thanks for your input and workaround! (oh and btw I was using 5.1 SDK actually)

Comment: I've implemented your method, Jesse, using a timer. The problem is, even 0.1s after the notification is receives on a tap from the notification center, the application state is still Inactive. Any tips?

Comment: Is it just a timing issue? What about after a longer period of time?