# Detect didReceiveLocalNotification coming from notification manager vs real-time

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uilocalnotification

When didReceiveLocalNotification is called, I would like to know if it is because a user clicked the notification from outside of my app, or if it is called because my app was the foreground app when the alarm occurred.  It is important to know the difference because in one case the user already got an alert with some info and doesn't need it again, in the other case they have not already received that info.

I am currently setting a flag in applicationWillEnterForeground and clearing in applicationDidBecomeActive.  If the flag is set when didReceiveLocalNotification is called, I know it is coming from outside of my app and the user already saw the system notification in some form.  However, I just noticed this flag will not be set if the user gets the notification, but doesn't click it yet (so it's just in the pull-down notification area), then clicks it from that area while my app is in the foreground.  In this case my app is already in the foreground, so the flag is set.

Ideally there would be a property set on UILocationNotification that I can check to get this info.

I suppose I could use the fireDate and say if it is less than 1 or 2 seconds old, and flag is not set, then I am getting the notification real-time, not at a later time.. but I prefer something more robust if possible.

Edit: Right as I was clicking save I noticed the "related" section had this link:

[iOS - Need to distinguish UILocalNotification in application:didReceiveLocalNotification:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11377197/ios-need-to-distinguish-uilocalnotification-in-applicationdidreceivelocalnoti)

Sorry for posting a duplicate question without searching more first (I did search, really!).  Hopefully maybe this will get a better answer though, since that one doesn't really have a robust answer -- but maybe there isn't one.